# how to make this thank quote sound more eloquent

Tags: word-choice

I am trying to write a thank quote and wanted to seek advice on how to make it sound more eloquent...

"To my joyful and loving /name of person/, who brings me the joy and peace to be able to do my work"

Are there better words for loving?  someone who has a lot of love to give and always give good love?

Apologies in advance but my native language is not english.

Comment: my joyful...who brings me joy - that's a horrible repetition. Bad style.

Comment: I'm sorry, Dnaiel, but we don't take questions asking us to help with specific phrasings or rewriting. I need to close this. You can try asking for help in our chat room: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/168/the-overlook-hotel

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a metaphor?

> For X, the fuel that keeps me going.

(Of course, something less cliched than that.)

Metaphors can make a quote more eloquent without sounding too cheesy.

Once I compared my relationship with a girl with a *ghost hunt*. And she actually cried (of joy, I think).

Comment: @Chen, I'd like to read such comparison, sounds quite a good one